# Is There Any Simple Way Available To Fetch Data Without RecyclerView In Android?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

My task is to obtain ID from user table and set that into Textview. My Database Schema is as below.

```
User ID     Int
Email       Varchar(255)
Password  Varchar(255)
```

I have searched many tutorials on google but most of the Tutorials found of Recyclerview,CardView,Adapter and DataList.

For Fetching ID from User Table is it compulsory to create four page coding?.

Is there not any simple way to obtain ID and set it to TextView?.

If there is simple way then suggest me simple coding.

Comment: please tell me about your code, do you use Rxjava for Threading? do you use Room library for your database?

Comment: @MohsenNaderzadeh I am searching for simple coding not yet coded. I am using Java Only.

Comment: @blackapps, Ok I have Edited My Post